# Fabric8 (Fuse ESB 6.1) strategy for deploying profile based on features

Tags: java, maven, fuseesb, jbossfuse, fabric8

I have an application currently deployed on Karaf 2.3.3 using feature deploys (and KAR alternative). Since I'm now trying out fabric8 I need some advice creating profiles using the maven plugin.

Should I create a profile based on the already existent profiles I've made for the project? Or should I package the bundles into a profile?

I'm running into problems when deploying either way. Just a fraction of the error log:

```
  io.fabric8.agent.utils.MultiException: Error while downloading artifacts
  at io.fabric8.agent.utils.AgentUtils$ArtifactDownloader.await(AgentUtils.java:314)
  at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentBuilder.download(DeploymentBuilder.java:160)
  at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent.doUpdate(DeploymentAgent.java:503)
  at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent$2.run(DeploymentAgent.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
java.io.IOException: Error downloading mvn:com.xxx.services.features/xxx-cassandra-feature/0.3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Maven plugin? Is is the fabric8 plugin you refer to?
http://fabric8.io/#/site/book/doc/index.md?chapter=mavenPlugin_md

You can just create a profile using the hawtio, where you can assign Karaf features / OSGi bundles and whatnot.

And then create a container with this profile, to have a JVM running this stuff.

And most often maven coordinates is used for downloading the code/JARs. The error you posted above indicate there is a problem downloading from the maven repositories defined.

But the fabric8 maven plugin is easier, as you just use it to create the profile, and upload your code/project to the maven server (proxy) that is built-in fabric.

The quickstart examples that comes with the ESB has the fabric8 plugin in their pom.xml you can enable and use as a sample.

Notice this requires latest build of fabric/Fuse ESB as the maven plugin is rather new.

Comment: Yes, that's the plugin. The POM artifacts exists in the localrepo. Using the latest Fuse ESB too. Manually creating the profiles is easy, but should be convenient to build a profile using the karaf features.xml already in place.
Think I figured the pluhgin out, but still have to manually delete the parent POM bundles from the profile using hawtio.

Comment: By the way, followed quickstart-jms (I have camel routes with amq) can't connect to the broker in the default profile I created, spent hours on this today... sigh

2014-03-06 21:35:37,985 | ERROR | datamart-update] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | .DefaultMessageListenerContainer  907 | 187 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms - 3.2.7.RELEASE_1 | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'datamart-update' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Stopped.

Comment: You need a broker as pre-requisite for some of the JMS examples. If you use FULL distro then it has a broker out of the box - if not then install a broker first, such as creating a container with the broker, or assign the broker to the root container. Yeah readme instructions of quickstarts needs to be improved.

Comment: and btw we are on irc chat, you can get much faster help there! - http://fabric8.io/#/site/doc/community.html

Comment: Thanks, appriciate it. Still stuck with connection errors. Created a broker in a container in the default group. Followed the quickstarts and removed much of the previous amq. connection factory settings in the blueprint.xml's. Tried with brokerURL=fabric:default" (or something, don't remember the exact setting now).

Checking in on IRC